# the mini-batch of deep and wide in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to get the deep&wide model working on a big data, for example([enter link description here](https://www.kaggle.com/c/avazu-ctr-prediction/data)
). 
Where the hidden units of deep side is [1024,512,256].

We use tf.SparseTensor() to store our data.

I get below error When I use 40 million instance as training data.

```
  ***

m.fit(input_fn=lambda: input_fn(df_train), steps=FLAGS.train_steps)                        
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 182, in fit
    monitors=monitors)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 458, in _train_model
    summary_writer=graph_actions.get_summary_writer(self._model_dir))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/graph_actions.py", line 76, in get_summary_writer
    graph=ops.get_default_graph())                                                             
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/summary_io.py", line 113, in __init__
    self.add_graph(graph=graph, graph_def=graph_def)                                           
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/summary_io.py", line 204, in add_graph
    true_graph_def = graph.as_graph_def(add_shapes=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2117, in as_graph_def
    raise ValueError("GraphDef cannot be larger than 2GB.")                                    
ValueError: GraphDef cannot be larger than 2GB.
```

---

So I want to use mini-batch as a solution to this problem, but it is not working. How do I use mini-batch to handle big data?

Comment: are you using a `tf.constant` to store your data?

Comment: I did not use a tf.constant, but use tf.SparseTensor().

Comment: I removed the batch-file tag, because your question has nothing to do with WIndows batch file programming. Please don't just randomly add tags because they sound familiar; tags have specific meaning here. When you're adding a tag, a description of that tag is shown to you so you'll know what it means.

Comment: @chris.guo did you figure out how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

To train with minibatches, you just call `model.train` multiple times per epoch, feeding it a subset of the data each time.  You can feed the data without loading it into the graphdef by either using `feed_dict` or by using one of the data reading ops described in the [reading data tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/reading_data).